# Website doesn't load on mobile version of chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment

I have a personal website at https://AmirSalar.net which opens perfectly fine on every desktop browser and every phone browser except chrome on both android and iOS

on my iPhone when I cleared the browsing data (cookies) the problem was solved but on every other phone it still doesn't load on chrome
any solution please?

Comment: Your site works perfectly fine on my Android Chrome. Tried with other browsers as well, works smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a couple of files doesn't load correctly, and it might break the intended functionality of your site.

- Failed to load resource: email-decode.min.js, the server responded
  with a status of 404 (Not Found)
- Failed to load resource: api.js, the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) rum:1
- Failed to load resource: rum, the server responded with a status of
  404 (Not Found) rum:1

Also a POST fails to https://amirsalar.net/cdn-cgi/rum? with 404 (Not Found).

Comment: thanks, so do u know how can I fix this issue? I'm a junior programmer

Comment: Sure, make sure to upload your resources to the correct location on the server. There might be an offset in the file structure (sub directories) or some cgi-bin folder adjacent to the web folder, in which script resources need to be placed. Also the resources need to be given correct access rights (especially if you are using a Unix/Linux system).
It is hard to give more exact description because I don't know how your file structure looks like.
I would also advice to ask a more senior person with access to the server to give you assistance.